# How to declare an imageIcon array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am somewhat new to Java, so excuse this really dumb question. I was just wondering, how does one declare a 2D array of ImageIcons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say like this:

```
ImageIcon[][] arr = new ImageIcon[10][5];
```

Note that after this line, the array elements will be uninitialized (they will be all equal to null).

If you want to initialize them, you need to loop through your array and call some of the `ImageIcon` constructors e.g.

```
arr[i][j] = new ImageIcon();
```

Comment: K thanks. A related question, how would I assign imagefiles to each elements in that array?

Comment: By calling some of the ImageIcon constructors e.g. this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.awt.Image%29